# Iapetos push! to push-gateway raises IOException, but push-gateway returned status 200

Tags: clojure, prometheus

Using clj-commons/iapetos to push metrics to a Prometheus push-gateway. The push appears to work. Push-gateway returns status 200, but I also get an IOException from the push! call.

I'm running Prometheus and it's push-gateway in Docker containers using docker-compose. If the containers are down, I get `Connection Refused` when I do the push.

I can also see the pushed metrics in the Prometheus dashboard.

Here's what the error looks like when the push is done from lein repl.

````
Execution error (IOException) at io.prometheus.client.exporter.PushGateway/doRequest (PushGateway.java:314).
Response code from http://127.0.0.1:9091/metrics/job/push-gateway was 200```
````

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been resolved.

[Iapetos](https://github.com/clj-commons/iapetos) version 0.1.9 is using io.promotheus version 0.6.0., which has a bug. The bug is fixed in version 0.8.0. Updating Iapetos to use io.prometheus version 0.8.0. fixes the problem.